# Strong Folner condition(SFC) implies the existence of a left Følner sequence.

Tags: ergodic-theory, semigroups, ramsey-theory, amenability

I got stuck with this problem while reading [Density in Arbitrary Semigroups](http://nhindman.us/research/density.pdf) by Hindman and Strauss. It says:

**Problem:** If $S$ is a countable semigroup. Then **SFC** on $S$ implies the existence of a left Følner sequence.

**Definition of SFC:** $\forall\; H\in \mathscr{P}_f(S),\; \forall\; \epsilon>0,\; \exists\; K\in \mathscr{P}_f(S)$ such that $\forall \; s\in H, \; |K\Delta sK|<\epsilon|K|$.

**Definition of left Folner sequence:** Let $S$ be a semigroup. A left Følner sequence in $\mathscr{P}_f(S)$ is a sequence $\{F_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ in $\mathscr{P}_f(S)$ such that for each $s\in S, lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{|sF_n\Delta F_n|}{|F_n|}=0$

($\mathscr{P}_f(S)$ stands for the set of all finite subsets of $S$).

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** Since $S$ is countable, you can construct an increasing sequence $H_1 \subset H_2 \subset ... \subset H_n \subset ...$ of finite subsets such that 
$$S= \bigcup_n H_n$$

For each $H_n$ you can find some $F_n$ such that 
$$
\frac{|sF_n\Delta F_n|}{|F_n|} < \frac{1}{n} \qquad \forall s \in H_n
$$

Show that $F_n$ is a left Følner sequence.

Comment: I almost tried in this way. But for each $H_m$, I was considering a Folner sequence $F_n^{(m)}$, and I thought, may be $F_n^{(n)}$ would work. Anyway, thank you very much for your help. Upvoted and accepted.